# Does FMJ deal more damage to the robot in Safeguard?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I know explosives do more damage than bullets, but if someone put the FMJ attachment on a gun--for example, the 48 Dredge--would it do more damage to the robot then not having FMJ at all?

Answer (score 1):

It did until they nerfed FMJ.
FMJ has been nerfed about a year ago and no longer inflicts increased damage to the robot.

[Source](https://twitter.com/DavidVonderhaar/status/686975402133159936)